# Obtener parámetros w0 y w1 con Theano dado el modelo: y = log (1+ wo|x|)+ w1|x|

Tags: python, theano

Estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio que tiene el siguiente enunciado:

Crea un conjunto de datos utilizando el siguiente código:

```
trX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
trY = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
for i in range(len(trY)):
trY[i] = math.log(1 + 0.5 * abs(trX[i])) + trX[i] / 3 + np.random.randn() * 0.033
```

Ahora, utiliza Theano para obtener los parámetros w0 y w1 del siguiente modelo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He encontrado un desarrollo parecido pero para otro modelo:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

trX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
trY = 2 * trX + np.random.randn(*trX.shape) * 0.33
X = T.scalar()
Y = T.scalar()


def model(X, w):
    return X * w

w = theano.shared(np.asarray(0., dtype=theano.config.floatX))
y = model(X, w)

cost = T.mean(T.sqr(y - Y))
gradient = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=w)
updates = [[w, w - gradient * 0.01]]

train = theano.function(inputs=[X, Y], outputs=cost, updates=updates,
                       allow_input_downcast=True)
for i in range(100):
for x, y in zip(trX, trY):
    train(x, y)

print(w.get_value())  # Resultado alrededor de 2.
plt.plot(trX, trY, 'g.')
plt.show()
```

¿Cómo sería el desarrollo para este modelo: y = log (1+ w0|x|)+ w1|x|?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días María Luisa,

Básicamente deberías cambiar la definición del modelo y crear dos variables compartidas (w y c) para cada uno de los parámetros del modelo

```
X = T.scalar()
Y = T.scalar()

def model(X, w, c):
    return X * w + c

w = theano.shared(np.asarray(0., dtype = theano.config.floatX))
c = theano.shared(np.asarray(0., dtype = theano.config.floatX))
y = model(X, w, c)
learning_rate=0.01

cost     = T.mean(T.sqr(y - Y))
gradient_w = T.grad(cost = cost, wrt = w)
gradient_c = T.grad(cost = cost, wrt = c)
updates  = [[w, w - gradient_w * learning_rate], [c, c - gradient_c * learning_rate]]

train = theano.function(inputs = [X, Y], outputs = cost, updates = updates)

coste=[] #Variable para almacenar los datos de coste para poder representarlos gráficamente

for i in range(101):
    for x, y in zip(trX, trY):
        cost_i = train(x, y)
    coste.append(cost_i)

w0=float(w.get_value())
w1=float(c.get_value())
print(w0,w1)
```

Espero poder haberte ayudado

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días María Luisa,

Y ha pasado mucho tiempo desde que hiciste esta pregunta y seguramente ya la tengas solucionada pero por si acaso te paso mi solución ya que tuve que realizar el mismo ejercicio.

Como dice VPA DRP es perfecto pero como detalle diría que cuando defines el modelo tienes que indicar la función del modelo con la que quieres trabajar. De tal forma quedaría:

```
def model(X,w,c):
    return log(1+w*abs(X))+c*X
w=theano.shared(np.asarray(0.,dtype=theano.config.floatX))
c=theano.shared(np.asarray(0.,dtype=theano.config.floatX))
y=model(X,w,c)

cost=T.mean(T.sqr(y-Y))
gradient_w=T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=w)
gradient_c=T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=c)
updates=[[w,w-gradient_w*0.01],[c,c-gradient_c*0.01]]

train=theano.function(inputs=[X,Y],outputs=cost, updates=updates)

for i in range(-1,101):
    for x,y in zip(trX,trY):
        cost_i=train(x,y)
W_0=float(w.get_value())
W_1=float(c.get_value())
print(W_0,W_1)
```